# Pick one option and assign value

Tags: string, list, z3, z3py

I have a list of items, and I want the solver to pick one item from the given list. I read we cannot assign values on SOLVER.

**For example:**
If I have string list
A = {"opt1","opt2","opt3"}
Solver condition "opt1" or "opt2"or "opt3"
the solver will SAT and pick one.

Any way to assign string value to do this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to decipher exactly what you're asking for; but this is of course entirely possible. It helps if you share your code and what you tried. Here's an example that might get you started:

```py
from z3 import *

opt1 = Bool("opt1")
opt2 = Bool("opt2")
opt3 = Bool("opt3")

s = Solver()

# Add some constraints on the options
s.add(Or(opt1, opt2))
s.add(Or(opt2, opt3))

# make sure only one is picked
s.add(If(opt1, 1, 0) + If(opt2, 1, 0) + If(opt3, 1, 0) == 1)

if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    if m.evaluate(opt1): print("picked: opt1")
    if m.evaluate(opt2): print("picked: opt2")
    if m.evaluate(opt3): print("picked: opt3")
```

When run, this prints:

```
picked: opt2
```

Depending on your other constraints, version of z3 etc., you can get an arbitrary setting this way that is consistent with your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm trying to translate <option> tag on HTML to z3py format. I will do your suggestion.